# Change span label font size in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I want to show a multiline text so I use a span label. I am trying to set the font size from the gui but it does not change.

I also trying to set the color dynamicaly using the next code:

```
this.gui_Span_Info.getAllStyles().setFgColor(HTMLElement.COLOR_RED);
```

but nothing happens.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

`SpanLabel` is a composite component which means it's built from 2 or more separate components one of which is a `Container`.

You can determine the UIID of the text using `setTextUIID` it defaults to the `Label` UIID.